# Netty: What are the differences between ChannelHandlerContext.channel().write() and ChannelHandlerContext.write()?

Tags: netty

I'm new to Netty. While I was browsing some examples of Netty project, I found that `ChannelHandlerContext.channel().write()` and `ChannelHandlerContext.write()` can both write response data to client. So what are the differences between them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Channel#write and ChannelPipeline#write write response from the tail handler context in pipeline.

```
// DefaultChannelPipeline # write
public ChannelFuture write(Object msg) {
    return tail.write(msg);
}
```

ChannelHandlerContext#write writes response from the next handler context.

```
// AbstractChannelHandlerContext # write
next.invoker().invokeWrite(next, msg, promise);
```

Comment: For `ChannelHandlerContext#write()`, what if current handler is the last handler?

Comment: @Neo DefaultChannelPipeline has a head and tail context , like headContext <- myhandlercontext <- tailContext, so the write operation will be operated by headContext